# Поведение кнопки при наведении на неё курсором

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Здравствуйте!
Нужно сделать так, с помощью css и html, чтобы при наведении на кнопку менялось название кнопки, например была кнопка "Заказать товар", а при наведении менялось на "Жми!".
И каким образом это же самое реализовать уже на jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такого поведения можно добиться только с помощью CSS и HTML без доп. сценариев, применяя псевдоэлементы [before](https://webref.ru/css/before) или [after](https://webref.ru/css/after) и их свойство [content](https://webref.ru/css/content). Для замены текста после наведения курсора мыши используется псевдокласс [hover](https://webref.ru/css/hover).

```css
.active-button::after {
  content: "Текст на кнопке";
}
.active-button:hover::after {
  content: "Нажми!";
}
```

```html
<button class="active-button"></button>
```

При изменении текста меняются размеры кнопки, что может негативно отразиться на UI, поэтому рекомендуется задать фиксированные размеры для вашей кнопки.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на `JQ`

```js
$('.active-button').hover(function() {
    $(this).text('Нажми');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).text('Текст на кнопке');
  }
);
```

```css
.active-button{
width:200px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="active-button">Текст на кнопке</button>
```